# Voice & Video Call in Laravel and Flutter

Tags: flutter, laravel-8

I want to implement **Voice Call** functionality in my app. I am working on **Laravel** and **Flutter**.

Please suggest me any package for the same that can be used for both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC. There are libraries for flutter and laravel